# how to print something that is not shown on the screen

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, printing

I've been struggling for while now in printing a document, 
the document have a header footer and body,
the body (which is a grid) have different size for each different document.
the document may have one of 2 sizes (A5,A4) depending on the rows count of the grid

I used ReportViewer control at first but there was a few problem with it, mainly it was printing 2 papers no matter what is the size of the document after 10 weeks of researching I gave up, nothing made any sense.

then I tried to print a form and all it's content (which wasn't easy) again problems surfaced,
one of them different screen resolutions, and the worse if the body have many rows the form will not fit the screen then it will not be printed.

**my question is:**
How does word print all the content of the page? what is the mechanism? 
I just need a head start , how to print something that is not shown on the screen?

Comment: I finally found a way to do it using WPF, I will post my code once I'm done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure if this is what you want but,

What you have to do is create a dummy form that's the size of the control you want to print then add the control to the dummy form and show the form and print the control on the dummy.

Here is how i did it:

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    //Create bitmap
    Bitmap image = new Bitmap(dataGridView1.Width, dataGridView1.Height);
    //Create form
    Form f = new Form();
    //add datagridview to the form
    f.Controls.Add(dataGridView1);
    //set the size of the form to the size of the datagridview
    f.Size = dataGridView1.Size;
    //draw the datagridview to the bitmap
    dataGridView1.DrawToBitmap(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, dataGridView1.Width, dataGridView1.Height));
    //dispose the form
    f.Dispose();
    //print
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0);
}
```

This will print dataGridView1, even if its not seen on the form.

Comment: If this work it will save me huge amount of time, thanks! I will try it out.